# Tcl: pass argument with square brackets to procedure (SDC)

Tags: parameter-passing, tcl, brackets, proc

I want to build a SDC simulator.
here's my proc:

```
proc set_false_path { body ... }
proc get_pins { body ...}
```

And I use tcl build-in "source" to read the SDC file, MY_SDC_FILE.sdc (there are lots file in MY_SDC_FILE.sdc)

In file, there is a command:

```
set_false_path -through [get_pins my_pin[1]]
```

It will report **"invalid command name "1"** error

I try to do proc like "proc 1 { body ...}", but is time-consuming if have case like [100000].
any way to fix error, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid this problem with appropriate quoting:

```
set_false_path -through [get_pins {my_pin[1]}]
```

Tcl's quoting rules are documented at https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot modify my_pin[1] with {}, this file is from others .

Comment: Well trying to `source` a file which does contain valid Tcl code is not likely to work I'm afraid.

Comment: Actually you could do a hack with https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/unknown.htm to catch the execution of `[1]`, `[100000]`, etc. and handle these somehow.

Comment: appreciate, it work now.